# Selling a used article

Tags: transactions, gezel-stealing

If I am selling my 2009 Camry am I allowed to have it detailed to give the appearance that it is “ like new”. See Rambam hilchos mechira 18:2, Choshon Mishpat 228:9, and B”M 60b
With the understanding “the world does it”

Comment: ואם תאמר בלבבך: ואיך אפשר לנו שלא להשתדל במשאנו ובמתננו לרצות את חבירנו על המקח ועל שוויו? חילוק גדול יש בדבר, כי כל מה שהוא להראות את הקונים אמיתת טוב החפץ ויפיו, הנה ההשתדלות ההוא טוב וישר. אך מה שהוא לכסות מומי חפצו, אינו אלא אונאה ואסור. וזה כלל גדול באמונת המשא והמתן. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%90

Comment: I don’t think anyone would think your 2009 car is new. So it’s obvious to the casual consumer that you detailed it. Your not hiding anything

Comment: You might like to submit your question to https://www.everydayemes.org/halachahotline .